# Inset Faces Giving Weird Results

Tags: modeling, topology

When I select the front face on this object and use the Inset Faces features, I get very weird results in the corners (see second image)

[image: Shield1]

[image: Shield2]

Things I have tried:

- Applying all transforms
- Merging vertices by distance
- Recalculating normals
- Manually checking for any weird/duplicate vertices around the areas that are causing problems

Nothing seems to help, but as I'm very new to Blender I assume I'm just doing something wrong (although from googling it and following other tutorials I can't see what). Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: hello, maybe share your file so that we can give a try? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the edges go in in their direction so as you can see they all go in the right direction, if you do not want this do E and then right click and then while the face is still selected Resize it with S and that will do the trick usually.

Side note, if you are using clipping on your mirror node it will not inset normally.

[image]

Comment: oh ok thanks, that seems a lot better. I guess I misunderstood what the inset faces option is meant to do (and now I don't really see the point of it existing if this other method works better)

Comment: it has it's uses